# Are Resque queues created by the main thread or workers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, redis, resque

I'm a little confused because I hadn't set up any workers (on Heroku) and when I did 
Resque.enqueue the job was added to the queue (but not completed) so I'm assuming the main thread generated the queue.

Since I'm using Redis To Go, wouldn't this defeat the purpose of using a background process like Resque since Redis To Go is itself an external hosted database so the initial write process by the main thread to add the job to the queue could be unpredictable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when you call `Resque.enqueue` is that Resque connects to the Redis database, and adds the information needed to call the job later. The worker then connects to Redis, pops off the first added job, does that, and repeats.

So yes, the "main" thread does connect to Redis. The fact that it's an external database doesn't really matter. I mean, for people using the Mongo database addons, the Mongo database is also externally hosted. The idea is that the job you want to execute takes longer than the time it takes to add it to Redis.

Comment: The job we're adding to the queue is to send email notifications (using the sendgrid addon on Heroku).  I wasn't sure if it made sense to use the main thread to make a call to an external application (redis to go) in order to avoid making a call to another external application (sendgrid).

Comment: Try to figure out the time it takes to send a mail through sendgrid, and the time it takes to add a job to the queue. If it's significantly faster to add it to the queue, go with that. Otherwise, it's just another step, and I'd remove the Resque part.

Comment: well.  that's the thing with calling external apps like sendgrid - it's totally unpredictable. Most of the time it takes absolutely no time at all but sometimes it stalls for 1-2 seconds.  i don't know how it will be to add a job to a queue using redis to go - so far it's been fast but we haven't been using it long enough to know really.

Comment: You could always switch to delayed_job, and add a worker to your app. This way the jobs will be executed locally. Otherwise I believe the only noticeable lag when using Redis To Go would be network latency.